# How to Assign Value to Specific Rows in Data Frame over a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, statistics

Dataset Example:

[image]

I have this Dataset where there are multiple rows, and columns in which we have Column: Transaction S.No which starts from 1 and goes up to the transaction happened on that day, what we want is to create a new column and assign a value of 1 to it, where for eg: for a customer there are multiple rows so multiple transactions ranging from 1 to.. etc. So if the highest transaction S.No is 5 for that customer, we want to assign a value of 1 to that particular row in the Index column and rest rows should be blank for that customer, similarly, for all the other customers, their highest transaction S.No should be getting the value 1, where only single transaction is done, like a customer with only 1 transaction, it should put 1.

```
df.groupby('Accession Number')['Transaction S.No'].max()
```

Tried this which says the max transaction for every customer number, but how to assign the 1 value to it now?

Comment: Solution deleted few seconds ago was super, only missing expected ouput.

Answer (score 0):

This answer works but is probably not the prettiest since pandas is really powerful if you understand it correctly.

```
for step in df.groupby('Accession Number')['Transaction S.No'].max().items(): 
    df.loc[(df['Accession Number'] == step[0]) & (df['Transaction S.No'] == step[1]), 'test'] = 1
```

What this does is iterate over the items found in the groupby. These items are tupels of the column name and the max value ('some Accession', 5).
The condition then looks for the right column and sets the value on a different column to 1.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much! But there's one thing, My Dataset has more than millions of rows, so this approach takes a lot of time, is there any other approach which can do this instantly?

Comment: Due to the fact that this only iterates over a set of values consisting of unique Accession Numbers and then assigning on the whole table it should be 'rather' quick. 
For further improvements I'm sadly not skilled enough yet.